# Cannot setup CNAME record to map Verio's domain to Azure's website

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I have a domain from Verio.com and have a website on Azure. 
My goal is to set up access to my Azure website. The final url should be:
http://www.tackettsmillbarber.com/home.htm

I have added a CNAME record using Verio's control panel:

```
www.tackettsmillbarber.com.      86400 IN A     207.46.147.148
www.tackettsmillbarber.com.      86400 IN CNAME tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net.
```

However, 24 hours later when I use [DigWebInterface](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.tackettsmillbarber.com&type=CNAME&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=), I don't see any sign that the CNAME record would work:

```
www.tackettsmillbarber.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):
tackettsmillbarber.com. 299 IN  SOA feed19.nameservers.net. hostmaster.rapidsite.net. 2014081123 7200 3600 604800 86400
```

When I tried to configure a custom domain with Azure, I receive this error:

```
A CNAME record pointing from www.tackettsmillbarber to tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.www.tackettsmillbarber to awverify.tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net was not found either.
```

I don't know what is still missing. Should I contact Azure's support or should I contact Verio's support?

UPDATE:

Here's my current configuration on Verio's site:
[image]

RESULT:

After talking to Verio's support, this problem cannot be resolved. I am pretty much at a dead end now as Verio does not support CNAME and Azure does not have any way to accept requests from a foreign domain without CNAME.

Verio's response:

> The problem here is that the DNS RFC prohibits putting a CNAME in to a
>   zone along with any other record with the same 'name'. This means that
>   you cannot have a 'www' CNAME record in the zone with the 'www' MX
>   record.
>
> Unfortunately the 'www' MX record is one of the default zone records
>   and cannot be removed. Because of this we cannot create a 'www' CNAME
>   record. Our system sees it as invalid and will not push it out to the
>   nameservers.
>
> Unfortunately we do not provide domain pointing/redirect services. The
>   best that I can do is point your domain to the IP address of the
>   tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net hosting server. However, for this to work the
>   server will have to be configured to accept requests for
>   tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting web site or web role? If it's about web site, then there are two things:
1. You need to have at least "Shared" mode of your web site. Go to "Scale" in windows azure portal to change it.
2. When you do this, go to configure section under "Domain Names" you should see "Manage Domains" button. Follow instructions there.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I did what you said and got the error at the end of my posted question.

Comment: I understand the requirement for using Custom Domain. This answer does not solve the problem of unable to set custom domain to point to Verio even when I have the feature enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the Verio console, have you:

- Added a A record that point your naked domain to the Azure Web Site
  IP Address?
- Added a CNAME record that point www to the A record ?
  Usually configured as @
- Added a CNAME record that point awverify to
  awverify.tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net?

In the Azure portal, have you:

- Added your naked domain? tackettsmillbarber.com
- Added the www subdomain? www.tackettsmillbarber.com

Here's a quick video I made that might be helpful: [www.azurerocks.com/JDDzhbB-8fk](http://www.azurerocks.com/JDDzhbB-8fk)

Try this:

- tackettsmillbarber.com - A - the Azure Web Site IP
- www - CNAME - @
- awverify - CNAME - awverify.tackettsmillbarber.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I updated my question with screenshot of my settings on Verio's site.

Comment: I am unable to add the `www - CNAME - @` record because Verio's control panel invalidates it. Please check my screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/Sm7LtXQJn2I

Comment: This answer does not solve to problem because domain providers such as Verio do not support a CNAME record. Please see my latest update of the question for detail.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but the problem you are experiencing with Verio does not apply to all registrars. For example, GoDaddy permits cross-domain CNAMEs of the type you are attempting.

I have transferred several domains from Verio to GoDaddy for this reason. But GoDaddy renewals are more expensive than Verio. I would suggest looking at other registrars as well, e.g. Google Domains (I don't know whether they support this type of CNAME or not).